# The difference between, onViewRecycled, onDetachedFromRecyclerView, and onViewDetachedFromWindow in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm having some trouble understanding the terminology used by the official documentation.  Specifically, there are the methods 
`onViewRecycled`, `onDetachedFromRecyclerView` and
`onViewDetachedFromWindow`.  What are the difference between these three?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There is a significant difference, even in their signature:

[`onDetachedFromRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onDetachedFromRecyclerView(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView)) - Called by RecyclerView when it stops observing this Adapter.

What you might have not noticed, there is a matching method always called before this one:

[`onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onAttachedToRecyclerView(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView)) - Called by RecyclerView when it starts observing this Adapter.

When you call `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)`, `adapter` receives call to `onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView)`. Then following call to `recyclerView.setAdapter(null)` will trigger `adapter`s `onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView)`.

You usually don't need to override this method except for some special circumstances (like keeping count of observed `recyclerView`s etc.).

---

[`onViewRecycled(VH holder)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onViewRecycled(VH)) is much simpler, it's called before sending `viewHolder` to `recycleViewPool`.

You can think of it as a "cleanup" method of [`onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)).

---

[`onViewDetachedFromWindow(VH holder)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onViewDetachedFromWindow(VH)) always follows a matching [`onViewAttachedToWindow(VH holder)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onViewAttachedToWindow(VH)). It's called in exact moment when viewholder is becoming visible or invisible (attach or detach calls).

If a `viewHolder` was detached but not recycled yet, it's possible it can receive `onViewAttachedToWindow(ViewHolder)` call again without needing to rebind data with `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: Just for the future reader, this part is not true at all.  **"You can think of it as a "cleanup" method of"**. Because there might be cases that specific view holder is not recycled.